# Not able to a https web service in ColdFusion 8

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, ssl-certificate, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-2016

We are trying to add a https web service via CFadmin in ColdFusion 8.

We have two ColdFusion applications. One on ColdFusion 2016 and other in ColdFusion 8.
The CF8 application consumes few of the Web services of CF2016 application.

Recently, we added SSL to CF2016 application. So now the URLs of this application are HTTPS.

After it, few of the modules of cf8 that were consuming the webservices of cf2016 stopped working.

We figured it out that we need to update the webservice urls in cf8 with https urls.

We tried to update the webservice urls in CFAdmin but with no success. ColdFusion doesnot allow us to do it. It shows one error message 
`Error creating web service. Please ensure that you have entered a correct Web Service name or URL.`

We have checked the WS url in browser. It's returning the WSDL XML.

After a bit of searching we found this link
http://www.richarddavies.us/archives/2006/02/enabling_web_services.php

It suggests to add the SSL certificate to ColdFusion's Java Keystore and restart ColFusion services. We followed the steps - Imported the SSL certificate to keystore and restarted coldfusion service. But no success. We also tried restarting the whole server.

Can some suggest what else needs to be done to add HTTPS webservice to ColdFusion 8. We are currently clueless.

Configuration:
App1(non ssl) - CF8-multiserver, java6,iis7.5, windows server 2008 r2
App2(SSL installed) - CF2016, java8, iis8.5, windows server 2012 R2

Comment: If the cert is new, I'm going to assume your not using ssl. I'm assuming your cert is using a connection type that java 6 doesn't support. If it is tls 1.2, you'll need a recent version of Java 8 witch CF8 doesn't support. Can you verify what your cert supports?

Comment: @Twillen How can we check that?

Comment: If using Windows, consider using CFX_HTTP5... even after you upgrade to CF2016 or CF2018.  https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/14dea9c5c0bf47b1d78b  No need to import any certs & work w/TLS 1.2 (even expired certs if you set SSLERRORS="OK".)

Comment: @Pankaj With Chrome you can see the information under the developer tools security tab. If it is tls issue I could find a dup, to link the question too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ColdFusion 9.0.0 TLSv1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383727/coldfusion-9-0-0-tlsv1-2)

Comment: The problem is caused by java6.  It doesn't support the newer SSL cert standards.  You need Java8+ to support TLS 1.1+.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest solution you can do is to upgrade the CF8 to cf2016.

If Windows 2003 Server as there is no support from Microsoft for TLS 1.1 or 1.2 in this server version.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2011/10/02/support-for-ssltls-protocols-on-windows/

Comment: @Pankaj My 2 cents: Upgrading may not be in the budget, but a _very_ strong argument can be made for the necessity of adding the upgrades to the budget. I wouldn't serve anything from servers as extremely old as Win2K3 or CF8. Both of those are just begging to be the entry point of a major breach of every computer on your network. There have been significant security updates since the last time either of those servers were even still under support. Plus, as you are currently seeing, the advancements in the underlying technologies are a tremendous benefit.